# boxsdkのJWTAuthをインポートしようとするとcannot import name 'appengine' from 'urllib3.contrib'のエラーが出る

Tags: python, pip

以下の極めてシンプルなコードを実行したところ，

```
 from boxsdk import JWTAuth
```

urllib3関連の以下のエラーが出てしまいました。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\user\requests_toolbelt\_compat.py", line 48, in <module>
    from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib import appengine as gaecontrib
ImportError: cannot import name 'appengine' from 'requests.packages.urllib3.contrib' (C:\user\urllib3\contrib\__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\user\boxsdk\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .auth import JWTAuth, OAuth2, CCGAuth
  File "C:\user\boxsdk\auth\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .cooperatively_managed_oauth2 import CooperativelyManagedOAuth2
  File "C:\user\boxsdk\auth\cooperatively_managed_oauth2.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .oauth2 import OAuth2
  File "C:\user\boxsdk\auth\oauth2.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ..session.session import Session
  File "C:\user\boxsdk\session\session.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ..util.multipart_stream import MultipartStream
  File "C:\user\boxsdk\util\multipart_stream.py", line 3, in <module>
    from requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder import MultipartEncoder
  File "C:\user\requests_toolbelt\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .adapters import SSLAdapter, SourceAddressAdapter
  File "C:\user\requests_toolbelt\adapters\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .ssl import SSLAdapter
  File "C:\user\requests_toolbelt\adapters\ssl.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .._compat import poolmanager
  File "C:\user\requests_toolbelt\_compat.py", line 50, in <module>
    from urllib3.contrib import appengine as gaecontrib
ImportError: cannot import name 'appengine' from 'urllib3.contrib' (C:\user\urllib3\contrib\__init__.py)
```

同様の案件が近日中に複数報告されており，試せそうな策は試したのですが解決に至らず，打つ手がない状態です。
ご知見をお持ちの方がいらしたらご助力を願えないでしょうか。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

**参考URL**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76175487/sudden-importerror-cannot-import-name-appengine-from-requests-packages-urlli
https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/35410
https://community.jeedom.com/t/cannot-import-name-appengine-from-urllib3-contrib/106921

**`pip freeze` の結果** (Python 3.11)

```
appengine-python-standard==1.1.1
attrs==23.1.0
boxsdk==3.7.1
cachetools==5.3.0
certifi==2023.5.7
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
cryptography==40.0.2
frozendict==2.3.8
google-auth==2.18.1
idna==3.4
mock==5.0.2
Pillow==9.5.0
protobuf==4.23.1
pyasn1==0.5.0
pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
pycparser==2.21
PyJWT==2.7.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3
requests==2.31.0
requests-toolbelt==0.10.1
rsa==4.9
ruamel.yaml==0.17.26
ruamel.yaml.clib==0.2.7
six==1.16.0
urllib3==1.26.15
```

Comment: 最近リリースされた `urllib3` の `2.0.0` で `urllib3.contrib.appengine.AppEngineManager` は[削除されています](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/releases/tag/2.0.0)が、想定(pip freezeで出力されているもの)に反して実際はこちらのバージョンが使われてしまっていませんか？ また、venvなどは使用されていますか？

Comment: 質問記事の「`pip freeze`の結果(Python 3.11)」には`urllib3==1.26.15`とあり、これなら動作するはずですが、実際には問題発生しているのではない別の環境のリストが提示されている可能性が考えられますね。あるいは何か環境変数とかモジュールの検索パス等をカスタマイズしていて別の環境のものが優先してimportされてしまうとか？

Comment: @hinaloe さん
ご質問ありがとうございます。環境はconda create で作っています。

Comment: @hinaloe さん
ご指摘からヒントを得てurllib3.__version__を叩いてみたのですが，どうやら2.0.2が読み込まれてしまっているようです。pip uninstall urllib3ののちにurllib3==1.26.15を試してみたのですが，やはり出力は変わりませんでした。。何が起こっているかサッパリです。。

>>> import urllib3
>>> urllib3.__version__
'2.0.2'

Comment: @kunif さん ご回答ありがとうございます。
sys.pathを叩き，最優先がカレントディレクトリ ' ' になっていることに気づき，lsを叩くと，いつインストールしたかも定かでないurllib3-2.0.2のライブラリ情報が確かにありました。。
ディレクトリを移動し，from boxsdk import JWTAuthを実行したところ正常に動作しました。凡ミスで大変申し訳ありません。

Comment: @hinaloe さん　上記の通り解決いたしました。大変参考になるご回答ありがとうございました。